# How to decode JSON nested array values in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, json

So I have this JSON string:

```
"{"Jan": [5, 10, 15, 20] , 
  "Feb":[20,10,"",22], 
  "Mar":[5,3,"",4], 
  "April":[10,"",1,2]
 }, 
 {"title":"Test Chart - Month v Value"}"
```

I am trying to extract the data so that I can access each one so that I can iterate through the array and sequentially output the data.

The best way I can think of is to simply create an array of arrays in PHP, store key and its values together and do a nested for loop. So the array should look like this:

```
[[Jan, 5, 10, 15, 20],[Feb, 20, 10, ,22], [Mar, 5, 3, , 4]]
```

Lastly I would like to know how to store this title value into its own variable.

Comment: Your original string is not valid JSON. You can't have two objects in the same JSON string. They need to be elements of another object or array.

Comment: as @Barmar  said that json is not valid (You can't have two objects in the same JSON string. They need to be elements of another object or array). your json need to be something like this:- https://eval.in/679188

Comment: Where did you get that invalid JSON string? You need to fix whatever created it to do it correctly.

Comment: @Anant I would actually do it something like `{"title": "blah", "data": {"Jan":[...], "Feb":[...], ...}}`

Comment: @Barmar  yes you are right.That will be more suitable structure

Comment: @btramisetty , check my code . it should be able to fulfil your request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string isn't valid json currently, but it does contain two valid json strings. The json_decode() function won't work on your string as-is, but it does work on each individual valid json string:

```
<?php

// INVALID JSON STRING - THIS WON'T WORK:
$json = '{"Jan": [5, 10, 15, 20] , "Feb":[20,10,"",22], "Mar":[5,3,"",4], "April":[10,"",1,2]}, {"title":"Test Chart - Month v Value"}';
print_r(json_decode($json));

// This works:
$json = '{"Jan": [5, 10, 15, 20] , "Feb":[20,10,"",22], "Mar":[5,3,"",4], "April":[10,"",1,2]}';
print_r(json_decode($json));

// This works:
$json = '{"title":"Test Chart - Month v Value"}';
print_r(json_decode($json));

?>
```

Ideally you would fix the source json, but it might be getting passed to you or retrieved from a system you have no control over.

If you can safely assume that the json will always have a structure like in your example, you could split the strings out doing something like this:

```
if (preg_match_all("/{[^}]*}/", $str, $matches)) {
  foreach ($matches[0] AS $json) {
    print_r(json_decode($json));
  }
}
```

This won't work if the json object contains other objects, which is why it depends on whether you can safely assume the structure will always be the same or not.

Comment: This is all true, but I don't think it answers his question about how to rearrange it into the 2-dimensional array that he wants.

Comment: Also, it would be helpful to know how I can split them into 2 strings where the title part is independently stored

Comment: @btramisetty You should fix the original JSON so it doesn't require that. There's no easy way to tell which comma is the one that you should split on.

Comment: @btramisetty  for easiest way try to make json something what Barmar says:-  `{"title": "est Chart - Month v Value", "data": {"Jan":[...], "Feb":[...], ...}}`

Comment: @btramisetty If you have control over how the json string is created, it would be best to create it as valid json, as others have suggested. However if the value is being passed to you or retrieved from a system beyond your control, the splitting method may work. If you can safely assume the json will always always have the structure from your example, you could split the strings - I'll update this answer with an example.

Comment: I ended up removing the title segment of the data so processing the information is feasible now. To access the data inside each array, I have to use 2-d array referencing with `foreach ($keys as $index1=>$key)` and a nested one being `foreach ($values as $index2=>$value)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<?php

$jsonData = '[{
    "Jan": [5, 10, 15, 20],
    "Feb": [20, 10, "", 22],
    "Mar": [5, 3, "", 4],
    "April": [10, "", 1, 2]
}, {
    "title": "Test Chart - Month v Value"
}]';


$array = json_decode($jsonData ,true);
$formattedArr = array();
$i = 0;

foreach($array[0] as $key=>$val) {

    $formattedArr[$i] = $val;
    array_unshift($formattedArr[$i],$key);
    $i++;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($formattedArr);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should format the JSON to what Barmar suggested (check your comments), currently your JSON string is not formatted properly.

```
$json = '{"title":"Test Chart - Month v Value", "data": {"Jan": [5, 10, 15, 20], "Feb":[20,10,"",22], "Mar":[5,3,"",4], "April":[10,"",1,2]}}'
```

This would change the string to the following PHP array:

```
print_r($arr = json_decode($json, true));

Array
(
    [title] => Test Chart - Month v Value
    [data] => Array
        (
            [Jan] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 5
                    [1] => 10
                    [2] => 15
                    [3] => 20
                )

            [Feb] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 20
                    [1] => 10
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 22
                )

            [Mar] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 5
                    [1] => 3
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 4
                )

            [April] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 10
                    [1] => 
                    [2] => 1
                    [3] => 2
                )

        )

)
```

Now you can access the data like so:

```
echo $arr['title'];
print_r($arr['data']);
print_r($arr['data']['Jan']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = '{"Jan": [5, 10, 15, 20] , "Feb":[20,10,"",22], "Mar":[5,3,"",4], "April":[10,"",1,2],"title":"Test Chart - Month v Value"}';

$out = json_decode($data, true);
$newArray = array();
foreach ($out as $key=>$value){
    if(is_array($value)){
        foreach($value as $key1=>$row){
            $value[$key1+1] = $row;     
        }
        $value[0] = $key;
        $newArray[] = $value; 
    }
}

echo json_encode($newArray);
```

Comment: When I ran this, output was missing the first number from each array.